# wrong order of data value labels in barchart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I am trying to add data values on the bars of my barchart created using lattice package. Below is the snapshot of my code.

Unfortunately, the values on the top of the bar are coming incorrect. For example on top of the bar which has a value of 3.02E-10 it shows 4.76E-10 and so on. Could someone help me to fix this issue.

```
enter code here

p <- barchart (one_cir$Value~one_cir$bias, horiz=FALSE,xlim=select_bias, ylim=yrange, data=one_cir,
        groups=droplevels(one_cir$Model),
        xlab=list("RVBS (V)",cex=1.3 ),ylab=list("Delay (ps)",cex=1.3 ), 
        main="SVT Circuit Analysis: Delay vs RVBS",
        panel = function(x,y,...){
        panel.barchart(x,y,...)
        panel.grid(h=-1, v=0, col="gray")
        panel.text(x,y,label = one_cir$Value, pos=1,cex=1.2)
                },scales=list(cex=1.2),
        auto.key=list(x = .81, y = 1, corner = c(0, 0),half=FALSE,points = FALSE, cex=1.2, rectangles = TRUE)
                 )
        print(p)
```

---

Sample data set

```
bias Circuits Model Temp Corner Parameter    Value

0.0     NOR2   11C   25   3-TT delay_DDC 3.02e-10

0.3     NOR2   11C   25   3-TT delay_DDC 3.79e-10

0.6     NOR2   11C   25   3-TT delay_DDC 4.92e-10

0.0     NOR2   11B   25   3-TT delay_DDC 2.90e-10

0.3     NOR2   11B   25   3-TT delay_DDC 3.66e-10

0.6     NOR2   11B   25   3-TT delay_DDC 4.76e-10
```

Comment: Please add a spanshot of what you are getting. I ran your code and it worked out fine.

Comment: panel.text(x+rep(c(.25,-.25),3),y,label = one_cir$Value[order(one_cir$bias)], pos=3,cex=1.2) sorry no time for more, will put in a fuller answer later

Answer (score 2):

I'm no lattice pro, but the following tweak to the panel.text() function ordered the labels correctly and, put the labels above their respective bars, rather than overlapping with the bars:

```
    panel.text(x + rep(c(.25, -.25), 3), y, label = one_cir$Value[order(one_cir$bias)], pos = 3, cex = 1.2)
```

Here is the output I got:

[image: lattice barchart with labels]

I don't know if there is a more latticy way to get the same result. I also left out the xlim and ylim args because I didn't have those objects. Here's the full code:

```
    one_cir <- data.frame(bias = c(0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.6), 
    Circuits = rep("NOR2", 6), 
    Model = rep(c("11C", "11B"), each = 3), 
    Temp = rep(25,6), 
    Corner = rep("3-TT", 6), 
    Parameter = rep("delay_DDC", 6), 
    Value = c(3.02e-10, 3.79e-10, 4.92e-10, 2.90e-10, 3.66e-10,4.76e-10)
    )

    library(lattice)
    p <- lattice:::barchart(Value~bias, horiz = FALSE, data = one_cir,
            groups = droplevels(Model),
            xlab = list("RVBS (V)", cex = 1.3 ), ylab = list("Delay (ps)",cex = 1.3 ), 
            main = "SVT Circuit Analysis: Delay vs RVBS",
            panel = function(x,y,...){
                panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
                panel.grid(h = -1, v = 0, col = "gray")
                panel.text(x + rep(c(.25, -.25), 3), y, label = one_cir$Value[order(one_cir$bias)], pos = 3,cex = 1.2)
            },
            scales = list(cex = 1.2),
            auto.key = list(x = .81, y = 1, corner = c(0, 0), half = FALSE, points = FALSE, cex = 1.2, rectangles = TRUE)
    )
    print(p)
```